# Cassandra timeout during read query (19 million result) at consistency ONE

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I have Cassandra cluster with 2 node. And my table structure is `<key, Map<list, timestamp>>`. I am trying to fetch all key that contains given list. My query look like

```
Statement select = QueryBuilder.select().all().from(tableName).where(QueryBuilder.containsKey("list", value)); select.setFetchSize(50000);
```

but i am getting cassandra timeout during read query.

I can decrease **setFetchSize** but it taking too much time to process 19 million row.

1. Can any one please suggest correct way to solve this problem?
2. is there any alternative available for this kind of problem?

Cassandra version = Cassandra 2.2.1

Comment: Can you please post the output of `desc table` and what are you trying to fetch.

Comment: CREATE TABLE test ( id text PRIMARY KEY, list map<int, timestamp>
) WITH AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL" "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}' AND comment = '' AND compaction = {'class':'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'} AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1 AND default_time_to_live = 0 AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000 AND max_index_interval = 2048 AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0 AND min_index_interval = 128;
**CREATE INDEX list_index_test ON test (keys(list))**;

Comment: is there any way to increase read_timeout through java code so that i can increase ** setFetchSize** up-to 200k. Max size of each row will be 200-250 bytes.

Comment: setReadTimeoutMillis in SocketOption class. but you have to find actual reason for the timeouts. Is it giving timeout for small size like 1000

Comment: no, it's not giving timeout exception for small size upto 20000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra data modeling best practices recommend not to use collections (list, set, map) to store a massive amount of data. The reason is that when loading the CQL row (SELECT ... WHERE id=xxx) Cassandra server has to load the **entire** collection in memory.

Now to answer your questions:

> 1. Can any one please suggest correct way to solve this problem?

Using secondary index to retrieve a huge data set (19 millions) isn't the best approach for your problem.

If your requirement is: give me all list which contains an item, the following schemas may be more appropriate

**Solution 1: manual denormalization**

```
CREATE TABLE base_table(
   id text,
   key int,
   value timestamp,
   PRIMARY KEY(id, key)
);

CREATE TABLE denormalized_table_for_searching(
  key int,
  id text
  value timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY(key, id));

// Give me all couples (id,value) where key = xxx
// Use iterator to fetch data by page and not load 19 millions row at once !!
SELECT * FROM denormalized_table_for_searching WHERE key=xxx;
```

**Solution 2: automatic denormalization with Cassandra 3.0 materialized views**

```
CREATE TABLE base_table(
   id text,
   key int,
   value timestamp,
   PRIMARY KEY(id, key)
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW denormalized_table_for_searching
AS SELECT * FROM base_table
WHERE id IS NOT NULL AND key IS NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY(key, id);

// Give me all couples (id,value) where key = xxx
// Use iterator to fetch data by page and not load 19 millions row at once !!
SELECT * FROM denormalized_table_for_searching WHERE key=xxx;
```

> 2. is there any alternative available for this kind of problem?

See answer for point 1. above :)

Comment: ok. But doing this way will increase size of table. Suppose if i have 30 millions unique id(row) and map corresponding to each row contain some 2000 (key, value) pair. Also size of both unique id(row) and (key, value) pair is continuously increasing. By splitting old table, new table will contains around 30*2000 rows. Is there any performance issue with new Cassandra table?

Comment: "Suppose if i have 30 millions unique id(row) and map corresponding to each row contain some 2000 (key, value) pair" --> You'll end up having 30 millions partitions, each counting 2000 clustering columns, perfect use-case for Cassandra because your 30 millions partitions will be distributed evenly on all nodes in the cluster.

Now if you want to fetch all the 30 x 10^6 * 2000 data points for processing, I'd suggest using Apache Spark. It is best suited for analytics use-cases